# Tinymce editor is not updated with separated components in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have using Tinymce editor in my vue 3, and i try to separate the Editor components. This is my Editor.vue components code:

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-mutating-props -->
<template>
    <div class="mb-6">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2" :for="id">
            {{ label }} <span class="text-red-600" v-if="isRequired">*</span>
        </label>
        <Editor :id="id" v-model="modelValue" :api-key="apiKey" @input="emit('update:modelValue', modelValue)"
            :init="editorInit" />
        <ValidationMessage :validation="validation" :field="id" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
import ValidationMessage from '@/components/ValidationMessage'

const apiKey = process.env.VUE_APP_TINYMCE_API_KEY

defineProps({
    isRequired: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: ''
    },
    validation: {
        type: Object,
        default: null,
    },
    editorInit: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({
            height: 500,
            selector: 'textarea',
            menubar: true,
            plugins: 'link image code lists',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | forecolor | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent numlist bullist | link image | code',
        }),
    },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

And i use that components to my Create.vue parents like this:

```
//other code
<Editor isRequired label="Deskripsi" id="description" v-model="course.fields.description" :validation="validation" />
//other code
<script setup>

import Editor from '@/components/Form/Editor'

const update = async () => {
    try {
        const updateFields = {
            description: course.fields.description,
        };

        console.log(updateFields);

        await course.updateCourse(router, {
            id: course.fields._id,
            data: updateFields,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        validation.value = error
    }
}
</script>
```

but why the `description` field value is not updated? I have other Input text components like this, and its working normally, but not with this tinymce editor

Comment: The only context we have for `description` is that it's assigned to the `id` prop of Editor and is maybe related to the `description` declared inside the scope of your `update` function.  How is the original `description` declared? How/where is your `update` function called?  What is `course.updateCourse` doing?  It's a black box we can't see inside unless you show us.  There's clearly a lot of steps involved.  What debugging have you done? What code have you verified is working and where does the failure begin?

Comment: original description is from my pinia course.js, and course.updateCourse is to update data from form to database. I have try console.log('updatefields'), but the course.fields.description is not change

Comment: Your response is unfortunately too vague.  What I'm trying to say is that you need to post more code and explanations of your code, enough to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  When you say "it does not change", well what was the expected value and what was the actual value?  is the emit working? is it a problem with updateFields not being correct?  you need to provide more technical details to receive a technical solution.  We unfortunately can't run your code to know how things are working so you must explain in detail.

Comment: Im sorry, its fixed now. I should use (at)change instead (at)input.